# Asp.net Button onclick event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a bit of a problem in the following code. I have asp.net button and its onclick event is not firing. I used breakpoints.

HTML code

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Style="width: 296px; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 30px; background: #f3b407;" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="LOGIN" />
```

C# code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EazySuppliesManager em = new EazySuppliesManager();
        string username = txtboxusername.Text;
        string password = txtboxpassword.Text;
        List<Customer> lsts = em.GetCustomerLogin(username, password);
        int count = lsts.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            txtboxusername.Text = "";
            txtboxpassword.Text = "";
            Customer cust = lsts.First();
            Session["Customer"] = cust;
            Response.Redirect("Index", false);
            login_btn.Attributes.Add("display", "none");
            lblusername.Text = "Welcome," + " " + cust.Username;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Customer"] = null;
        }
    }
```

This is how the button looks in the browser when I debug

```
   <input type="submit" style="width: 296px; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 30px; background: #f3b407;" class="btn btn-info" id="btnSubmit" value="LOGIN" name="ctl00$btnSubmit">
```

See, there is no onlclick event here. Just need a bit of a help in this.
Thanx in advance

Comment: The `onlclick` would be rendered only if you set [`UseSubmitBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`(default is true). I guess that a javascript error is responsible for the page not posting back. Does the page not post back at all or just not go into the event-handler?

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. Never used this attribute before. It used to work without this too. Don't know why this attribute now :/
Thanx though :)